# Can't figure out how to copy between VIM terminals on OS X

Tags: macos, vim, terminal, copy, clipboard

I know I need to copy into the " or * registers or something like that

Let's say I have one c program in one terminal running vim and another program in another terminal...

How do I copy a line between them?

Comment: run `vim --version` and look to make sure clipboard support is compiled in.

Comment: usually console clients (as putty) copy the selected text when you highlight it with the mouse (sometimes you will also need to click intro to accept it)

Answer (score -1):

Visually select the line you want to copy with `V`.
Hit `"*y` to yank the line into the * (clipboard) register.
Open the other terminal and vim inside it.
Hit `"*p` to paste or press `i` and then paste the info in there (like you would normally copy paste).

**If this does not work then you may need to run `vim --version` and see if your copy of vim is compiled with a `+clipboard`. If it says `-clipboard` then  you will need to install a version of vim that was compiled with clipboard. Results may vary when ssh-ing into a server.**